# Can we associate jobs with depots in case of multiple depots in Jsprit?

Tags: jsprit

Can we associate jobs with depots in case of multiple depots in Jsprit??

Let's say i have multiple depots in the same city and i want to restrict the service to a particular location by a specific depot, how can i achieve that in Jsprit ?

Comment: try modeling them as shipments?

Comment: No @HeHuang, i didn't try that, let me see how to achieve that.

Comment: @garvit what was the outcome?

Comment: It worked for me, you can define shipments and specify the pickup and delivery locations .. @roganjosh ....